# Android 5.1 loses the application, moved to system/app

Tags: android, android-5.1.1-lollipop

I use instructions to install application to Nexus 7 (2013) as system/app: http://howto.highonandroid.com/android-how-to-tutorials/how-to-install-user-apps-as-system-apps-on-your-android/2/
1. Install my app to data/app by system installer
2. Move full folder com.example.hellojni-1/ to system/app by X-plore
3. Change com.example.hellojni-1/ to rwx r-x r-x
4. Change com.example.hellojni-1/lib/ to rwx r-x r-x
5. Change com.example.hellojni-1/lib/arm/ to rwx r-x r-x
6. Change com.example.hellojni-1/lib/arm/libhello-jni.so to rw- r-- r--
7. Change com.example.hellojni-1/base.apk to rw- r-- r--
8. Reboot
9. Application hide from apps

I 've try to use some apps like "System App Manager", "System apps Installer", "System App Converter", but all with the same result - application hide.

Comment: It's possible that the OS checks on startup that the apps in system/app are actually valid system apps and is ignoring (or removing) ones that aren't.

Comment: all files in the system/app are the same after reboot, but hellojni hide from applications

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well two things:

1)On 5.0+ its actually /system/priv-app for a system app.  /system/app is for preinstalled non-system apps now.

2)That's not the right way to do it anyway.  You make a folder in /system/priv-app with the correct name.  Then you move the apk into it and reboot the device.  You do not install it then move the data directory.  Make sure the directory has mode 755 and the file is 644

Comment: 1) copied com.example.hellojni-1/ to a /system/priv-app with the same behavior 2) copied HelloJni.apk to a /system/priv-app with the same behavior. All my directorys has mode 755 and the files is 644

Comment: Did you make a priv-app/HelloJni folder and put the apk in that?  Then reboot the device (when it reboots it will find and install the apk).

Comment: Yes, I try both cases (priv-app/HelloJni/HelloJni.apk and priv-app/HelloJni.apk)

Comment: can you try the same with ESFile Explorer using this script: su -c "cp -r -p /data/app/com.estrongs.android.pop-1/ /system/priv-app/ESFileExplorer/";su -c "chmod -R 777 /system/priv-app/ESFileExplorer/";su -c "rm -rf /data/app/com.estrongs.android.pop-1"